# Unit testing in typescript with mocha

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, sinon

I'm starting with unit testings and I'd like to unit test my routes with sinon and mocha

My controller looks like this :

```
import { NextFunction, Request, Response, Router } from 'express';


export default class Sample {

  constructor(a: string) {
    console.error('constructor',a);
  }

  public getAll(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
    res.json('OK');
  }
}
```

This is what I did so far to test it :

```
import { expect } from 'chai';
import 'mocha';
import * as sinon from 'sinon';  

import Sample from './../controllers/Sample';
import { Response, Request, NextFunction } from 'express';

describe('Hello function', () => {

  it('should return hello world', async () => {
    const sample = new Sample('sample');

    const req: Partial<Request> = {};
    const res: Partial<Response> = {
      json: sinon.stub(),
    };
    const next: Partial<NextFunction> = {};

    await sample.getAll(<Request>req, <Response>res, <NextFunction> next);
    const expectedResult = 'OK';

    sinon.assert.calledWith(
      res.render as sinon.SinonStub, 
      'OK');      

  });

});
```

However I got the following error :

```
constructor sample
    1) should return hello world


  0 passing (39ms)
  1 failing

  1) Hello function
       should return hello world:
     AssertError: fake is not a spy
      at Object.fail (node_modules/sinon/lib/sinon/assert.js:96:21)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no `res.render` and it's not being called. `as sinon.SinonStub` type assertion was likely used to suppress type error that could be reported at compilation time otherwise.

Since it is `res.json('OK')`, it should be:

```
sinon.assert.calledWith(res.json, 'OK');
```